# How do I load jQuery background-check plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use the jQuery background check plugin(http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/) but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working ?

Here is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/n9o5jy4t/

```js
 BackgroundCheck.init({
     targets: '.checkbg'
 });
```

```css
#header_img_over {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(28, 28, 34, 0.9);
    filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: 2;
}
.header_bg {
    z-index: -10;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 245px;
    min-height: 245px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.header_bg img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
}
/* The Background _Checked */
.checkbg.background--dark {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="blog_title">
     <h2 class="checkbg">Test_title</h2>

</div>
<div id="header_img_over">
    <div class="header_bg">
        <img src="http://stylrs.com/v05/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ML_Guildhall_TBL_0009-767x415.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no errors in the fiddle. you have jquery and the plugin included in your code? in what order? what error do you get? any 404's?

Comment: I heave the plugin included in the <head> section and  I am running the small script inside the html within <script> tags just before the area for which I want to change colour. The errors I get are elements not found: g a here is a screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/1hcmmx/8

Comment: Also the plugin doesn't seem to be working in the jsfiddle preview? yet I think I have followed all of the directions provided

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it working into a Fiddle due cross origin problems, which made me give it a try into my server.

It seems you are forced by background-check script to have your images placed in the same server as the webpage. Here are two examples: [the working one](http://www.100px.com/tmp/esw3w5/index.html) and [the failing one](http://www.100px.com/tmp/esw3w5/index-fail.html).

As you can see on source, they are exactly the same but for the image url.

Hope it helps to lead a way to solve the issue :)

Comment: Hi thanks, but how are you running the actual script? is it just in a script file  or inline? I mean :  BackgroundCheck.init({
     targets: '.checkbg'
 });

Comment: It's called within the script tag starting on line 42.

Comment: @Lucas_T , the fact is that it seems like the Background Check script doesn't work with images hosted on a server other than the one which actually host the webpage that call it. Is it your case?

Comment: @Lucas_T did the server's image hint help you to make it work?